# Calculate days between now and a future date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I need to calculate how many days are left from today to a certain date in the future in Google Sheets.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible options for you to consider.

### Formula

1. `"28/06/2015"-TODAY())`
2. `DATEDIF(TODAY(), "28/06/2015", "D")`

Todays date is: `28/10/2014`. The result will be an integer (243).

### Note

Make sure to format the outcome as a number and not a date. If you choose the `NOW()` formula, you introduce a time component. This will break up the calculation and show decimals.

Answer (score 3):

```
=DAYS("01/01/2050", TODAY())
```

```
=DAYS(A2, TODAY())
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, this formula will do it:

```
=round(abs("2014-01-08"-NOW()),0)
```

Where `"2014-01-08"` is the date in the future.

Comment: If its minus, then it doesnt show that.